# Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I've recently started to use SQLite and began to integrate it into a C# project I'm working on.

However, randomly my project will throw the exception:

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

I'm having a hard time trying the trace the problem because it seems to be thrown on a random basis.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

//exception is thrown here
table = Global.db.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM vm_manager");
```

Some of the data that gets returned from this query is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rlLN.png

If anyone has any advice, I'd be grateful.

**EDIT:**  I'm unable to show the execute query function as it resides inside a dll from the following sql lite wrapper http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/cs_sqlitewrapper.aspx

**EDIT 2** Problem stems from the new record array function inside this particular sql lite wrapper.

Comment: Let us see the code inside `db.ExecuteQuery`.

Comment: The SQLite Wrapper's source is at http://pastebin.com/AjGaX0kL

Comment: what datatypes are your columns on that table? Do you have any nulls? Does the data change frequently, on the same scale as the exceptions are encountered?

Comment: The data changes more frequently than the exceptions which makes it even more confusing. There are no nulls. Data types are just ints, and text fields. I've currently setup a try catch and waiting for the exception to be thrown again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your SQLite wrapper's implementation, it is adding columns to its own internal DataTable before returning to yours. I suspect your defect is in the wrapper, and not in your code. I dug into the source of your SQLiteWrapper from CodeProject; here it is at PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/AjGaX0kL

I suspect the error is occurring in that helper method `ExecuteQuery()`, or its helpers: `ReadFirstRow()` or `ReadFirstRow()`, and not your code.  **Wrap your code in a `try catch`. Inspect the `Exception`, and the properties will tell you which method this exception is actually being created in.**

Likely you're encountering a defect in this wrapper class.

```
try
{
    DataTable table = Global.db.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM vm_manager");
}
catch (Exception ex){
//who threw this from which method and line?
}
```

If this SQLite provider isn't working, suggest evaluating:

- [System.Data.SQLite - An open source ADO.NET provider for the SQLite database engine](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)
- [ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/) -- and here's a nice [tutorial by Mike Duncan on this SQLite provider](http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/).

Comment: Assuming he's using a `SqlCommand` object or some such, this is done for him. As the asker said, this is random, not every time.

Comment: When the exception is thrown I can see the columns are already populated inside the datatable - so I'm not sure if columns are the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @p.campbell: I take back what I said. He probably *is* doing this manually.

Comment: Thanks p.campbell, I've setup a try catch, waiting for the exception to throw itself again.

Comment: I think i'll go ahead and get a new wrapper this one seems old anyway, I only used it as a quick demo. Anyone got any recommendations of sql lite c# wrappers? I'm basically looking for something really simple to throw into my project.

Comment: @Adam: have you tried System.Data.SQLite -- from PhxSoftware. http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I shall have a look into it.

Just an update on my problem it appears to be tied down to the new record from array function

http://yourimg.in/j/vs10z3t.png

Thanks for the help.